# Change discord bot name using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, discord.net

I am trying to make my own discord bot using `VB.Net` and I want to add command what change bot name command is working but name changing don't work and I don't know how to fix it.

my attempt #1

```
Dim Client As Discord.IDiscordClient
Dim Guild As IGuild = Await Client.GetGuildAsync("256776363892015115")
Dim user = Guild.GetUserAsync(Discord.CurrentUser.Id)
Await user.Result.ModifyAsync(New GuildUserProperties With {
      .Nickname = "Kissa"
})
```

my attempt #2

```
Discord.GetGuild("256776363892015115").GetUser(Discord.CurrentUser.Id).ModifyAsync(New GuildUserProperties With {
      .Nickname = "asd"
})
```

Images about code:

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

Version 0.9:

```
var user = Discord.GetGuild("256776363892015115").GetUser(Discord.CurrentUser.Id);
await user.Edit(nickname: "MySuperBot");
```

Version 1.x

```
var guild = discordClient.GetGuild(256776363892015115);
var user = guild.GetUser(discordClient.CurrentUser.Id);
await user.ModifyAsync(x => {
    x.Nickname = "MySuperBot";
});
```

Comment: That code is in c# and i already find that same code
i need that code to be in vb.net

Answer (score 0):

```
discord.GetGuild("256776363892015115").GetUser(discord.CurrentUser.Id).ModifyAsync(Function(x)
                                                                                           x.Nickname = "MySuperBot"
                                                                                       End Function)
```